# Why exactly HTML form does not support PUT and DELETE

Tags: html, http

Good day to all
I know guys this type of question was asked in the site bunch of times and since almost most of them explain in a superficial manner I decided to ask this question and implore you explain it with your own words and without providing links to other websites and try to explain in simple words: Why HTML forms supports only GET and POST and why exactly PUT, Patch and DELETE was dropped in HTML5. I hope for your understanding

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: [Why are there are no PUT and DELETE methods on HTML forms?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/114156/why-are-there-are-no-put-and-delete-methods-on-html-forms)

Comment: @Stijn, yes yes I know about this link I have read it and hostly did not understand much thus I decided this question. If possible, can you explain with your own words:)

Comment: Ok, short version is people disagree on its usefulness, and nobody has bothered to write out a specification to propose.

Comment: @Stijn, thank you for your attention dude but since I am beginner   is it possible for you to explain to the beginner just why they were removed from HTML5 since I am sure the removal action could not be done arbitrarily and without reason   if not ok just ignore my message I will understand since uually experts do not have time to explain simple subjects :)

Comment: I get the impression you think they were there in HTML4 and removed in HTML5, which is not the case. They were temporarily added to HTML5 but removed again because the people who decide on the spec could not agree with eachother.